# How do I remove an asterisk (*) from a the text contained with a <td> using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a table column definition that looks like this:

```
<td class="dvRequiredField validationFailed">
    *&nbsp;
    <input name="ctl00$MainContent$dvCustomer$ctl04" type="text" title="First Name" class="validationFailed">
    &nbsp;Required Field.
</td>
```

How do remove the "asterisk"  (or in a sense replace it with '') using jquery?

**I've tried the following:**

```
$('td.validationFailed').each(function () {
    $(this)[0].innerHTML = $(this)[0].innerHTML.replace(/\*/g, '');
});
```

It does not work. It replaces/removes the text value of my input control.

Thanks,
 JohnB

Comment: seems to be fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Apcch/1/ even though it can be written as http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Apcch/2/

Comment: `$(this)[0].innerHTML` is rather pointless. Just do `this.innerHTML`

Comment: however, if you only need to target the first text node, then use `this.firstChild.textContent` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/S2Vdt/)

```
$('td.validationFailed').contents().filter(function() { 
    return this.nodeType == 3 && this.wholeText.indexOf('*') > -1; 
})
.remove();
```